# How to get cover photo of facebook album in facebook API using C#?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get Cover_Photo of facebook album. I get everything expect Cover_photo. Can anybody please suggest me?

Code:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", Token);
var host = "https://graph.facebook.com/";
var json = await client.GetStringAsync($"{host}me/albums");
//Tried with following but didn't worked
//var json = await client.GetStringAsync($"{host}me/albums?fields=cover_photo,id,created_time,name");
var data = JObject.Parse(json).First.First.ToString();
var albums = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FacebookAlbum[]>(data);
```

JSON Response

> {"data":[{"created_time":"2018-08-08T07:04:25+0000","name":"Mobile
>   Uploads","id":"13015168813147"},{"created_time":"2018-08-08T07:00:25+0000","name":"Test2","id":"13014888880115"},{"created_time":"2018-08-08T06:59:16+0000","name":"Test1","id":"130148257913489"}],"paging":{"cursors":{"before":"MTMwMTUxNjc3OTEzMTW1","after":"MTMwMTQ4MjU3OTEzNDR$"}}}

One of support link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.1/album

Comment: It should work, if you ask for the field. Not every album necessarily has a cover photo set though.

Comment: @misorude it doesn't work if I pass the fields. Can you please review my code which is having comment line for field? Please suggest

Comment: Then I suggest you test your request in Graph API Explorer first, that way you’ll see whether it’s a problem with the request, or your code.